# Retrieve the first href from a div tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, href

I need to retrieve is the href containing `/questions/20702626/javac1-8-class-not-found`. But the output I get for the code below is `//stackoverflow.com`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=incorrect+operator"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
    if tag.get("class")==['summary']:
        for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
            if tag.get("class")==['result-link']:
                for link in soup.find_all('a'):
                        print link.get('href')
                    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making nested loops, write a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for link in soup.select('div.summary div.result-link a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

Which is not only more readable, but also solves your problem. It prints:

```
/questions/11977228/incorrect-answer-in-operator-overloading
/questions/8347592/sizeof-operator-returns-incorrect-size
/questions/23984762/c-incorrect-signature-for-assignment-operator
...
/questions/24896659/incorrect-count-when-using-comparison-operator
/questions/7035598/patter-checking-check-of-incorrect-number-of-operators-and-brackets
```

Additional note: you might want to look into using [`StackExchange API`](https://api.stackexchange.com/) instead of the current web-scraping/HTML-parsing approach.